# SQL Server 2008 R2: Pivot table with count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table

I have the following table to pivot.

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_Month
(
    EMPID int,
    [Month] varchar(10)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(101,'July');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(102,'June');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(103,'May');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(104,'April');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(105,'March');

INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(201,'July');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(202,'July');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(203,'June');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(204,'July');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(205,'June');

INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(301,'January');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(302,'January');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(303,'February');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(304,'February');
INSERT INTO Emp_Month VALUES(305,'February');
```

**Expected Output**: I want to print the COUNT(last_months_from_current_date)

```
Last_6_Month    Last_5_Month    Last_4_Month    Last_3_Month    Last_2_Month    Last_1_Month
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13              10              9               8               7               4
```

**My try**:

```
select *
from 
(
    SELECT t.Month,t.[Month] as Mon
    FROM Emp_Month t
) src
pivot
(
  COUNT(Mon)
  for [Month] in ([Last_6_Month],[Last_5_Month],[Last_4_Month],[Last_3_Month],[Last_2_Month],[Last_1_Month])
) piv;
```

But getting all zero values.

Comment: Are we to assume that `Track_Table` and `Emp_Month` are one and the same? Also, is your data really strings containing month names rather than `date` values?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Edited table name. And yes the month is string.

Comment: I'm looking at your expected results now and realizing, you want the count of last 6 months to include all the rows in February - July, and the last 5 months count to include all the rows in March - July, etc.  Is that right?

Comment: @Greenspark, Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this twisted my head a bit.  But this will do what you're asking.

The thing you are missing is that to do a running total, you have to have some way to order your set.  So there's construction here for getting a month number.  It's not the best but it is working for the example.

After grouping and doing the running total, a pivot is a bit over the top, but you were asking for one and so here you go.  Hope it helps.

(*I made some changes to the accepted answer to make the column headers of the pivot self-updating.  Otherwise, you would have needed to modify this every month)

```
;WITH 
    MonthsCountedOrdered AS
    (
        SELECT count(EMPID) empCount, Month, Datediff(M,  [Month] + ' 1, 2017', getdate()) + 1 monthsPast 
        FROM Emp_Month 
        GROUP BY [Month]
    )
    , RunningTotal AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Month
            , SUM(empCount) OVER (Order By monthsPast ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) tot
            , 'Last_' + cast(monthsPast as varchar(2)) + '_Month' as ColumnHeader 
        FROM
            MonthsCountedOrdered
        WHERE
            monthsPast <= 6
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT t.ColumnHeader,t.tot
        FROM RunningTotal t
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      Sum(tot)
      for [ColumnHeader] in (Last_6_Month,Last_5_Month,Last_4_Month,Last_3_Month,Last_2_Month,Last_1_Month)
    ) piv;
```

Result:

```
Last_6_Month Last_5_Month Last_4_Month Last_3_Month Last_2_Month Last_1_Month
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
13           10           9            8            7            4
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you've got a problem hardcoding `[Month] + ' 1, 2017'` - this code will only work when dealing with dates that are in 2017.

Comment: @StanShaw That's definitely true.  I had particularly noted in my response that the date logic is weak.  But, since the source data doesn't give any insight into what year we are talking about, so we're kind of stuck.

Comment: Exactly - I noticed he didn't have the year in his sample data - I just wanted to add the comment for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

@MAK here's your query that you tried:

```
select *
from 
(
    SELECT t.Month,t.[Month] as Mon
    FROM Emp_Month t
) src
pivot
(
  COUNT(Mon)
   for [Month] in ([Last_6_Month],[Last_5_Month],[Last_4_Month],[Last_3_Month],[Last_2_Month],[Last_1_Month])

) piv;
```

The Following line in your query needs to have actual values in the **MON** column. From your sample, it seems as if the actual month names are in there, though you're putting in your own values, hence the number will be 0. Try putting in the month names which you actually have.

for [Month] in (*[Last_6_Month],[Last_5_Month],[Last_4_Month],[Last_3_Month],[Last_2_Month],[Last_1_Month]*)

something like:

for [Month] in ([June],[July],[April])

Comment: But i want the count of last 6,5,4,3,2,1 months as shown in the expected result.

Comment: Pivot will use the values in your table as the names of the columns in the pivoted result.  That's how the technology works.  If you want to rename the columns, then give them aliases in your top select.

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all be counting the EMPID field rather than the Month, though both will work in this case.

Also you have nothing for it to pivot as none of the data in the Month Column matches your column list within your pivot. If you want to look at pivoting on last 6 months, then you'll have to add a new column or create a view or sub-query to add a column with values showing [Last_6_Month]

If you just want to count the months then you can always just use

```
    SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT t.Month,EMPID
    FROM Emp_Month t
) src
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(EMPID)
  FOR [Month] in (
  [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],
  [August],[September],[October],[November],[December]
  )
) piv;
```

Answer (score 0):

By dynamic sql approach i did this,This might be your required code

```
DECLARE @DynamicCol NVARCHAR(max), 
        @Sql        NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @DynamicCol = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename([month]) 
                            FROM   #emp_month 
                            FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') 

SET @Sql=N'SELECT  ' + @DynamicCol  + 'FROM  
            (
         SELECT t.[MONTH],COUNT(t.[Month]) AS Mon     
         FROM #Emp_Month t GROUP BY [MONTH] 
         )AS SRC 
         PIVOT 
         ( 
         MAX([Mon]) FOR [Month] IN (' + @DynamicCol + ') 
         ) AS PVT ' 

PRINT @Sql 

EXEC (@Sql)
```

You can set the below condtion also

```
SET @Sql=N'SELECT  ' + @DynamicCol  + 'FROM  
            (
         SELECT t.[MONTH],t.[Month] AS Mon     
         FROM #Emp_Month t 
         )AS SRC 
         PIVOT 
         ( 
         COUNT([Mon]) FOR [Month] IN (' + @DynamicCol + ') 
         ) AS PVT '
```